# What company created IIS and or who did microsoft buy iis from

Tags: iis

Who did microsoft purchase IIS from?

I know the wiki says that they created it, but I am pretty sure they purchased it from another company.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of SQL Server, which was originally a port of the Sybase SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services):

> Internet Information Services (IIS, formerly Internet Information
>   Server) is an extensible web server **created by Microsoft** for use with
>   the Windows NT family.
>
> **History**
>
> The first Microsoft web server was a research project at the European Microsoft 
>   Windows NT Academic Centre (EMWAC), part of the University of
>   Edinburgh in Scotland, and was distributed as freeware. However, since
>   the EMWAC server was unable to handle the volume of traffic going to
>   Microsoft.com, Microsoft was forced to develop its own web server,
>   IIS.
>
> - IIS 1.0 was initially released as a free add-on for Windows NT 3.51.

Both research and development appear to have started at Microsoft.